# Parent/Child ComboBoxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have 2 combobox, each having different items but somehow it's a hierarchy of characteristics of the next combobox ie:
Combobox1 has VEHICLES, MOTORBIKES and NONE as items. I want to be able to choose Vehicles in combobox1 and Combobox2 updates with items only associated with vehicles ie Sportscar, Sedan etc. The same should happen when I choose Motorcycles in combobox1, it should update combobox2 with items only related to motorcycles.

Comment: *"Another thing"*. No, not another thing. You must only ask one question at a time. If you have two questions, post two separate questions, each with a title that actually describes the topic of that question, not some vague title that describes neither.

Comment: Regarding the first question, which is the only question that should be posted here, you should read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065).

Comment: I have deleted your second question and modified the title to reflect your actual question. Please repost the second question with the information appropriate to that question and a title that summarises that topic. That said, you should put some thought into the problem and make an attempt for yourself first. Surely you know how to perform an action when something happens, e.g. save data or close a form on a `Button.Click`. What's the difference?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am here to learn! Literally from square 1.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the link you gave me is totally confusing me, a first beginner. Right now I am just working on designing the form and those primary controls commands. I haven't linked my work to any table or databases yet.

Comment: *"I haven't linked my work to any table or databases yet"*. So what? There's no database in my example. Did you even bother following the instructions I provided? Did you consider posting to that thread to ask a question about what confused you? Did you make some sort of effort on your own behalf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this sample code inside the **ComboBox1_TextChanged Event** for you to have reference.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged

        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        If ComboBox1.Text = "Vehicles" Then
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Sportscar")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Sedan")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Motorbikes" Then
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Harley Davidson")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("Some motorbikes")
        End If


    End Sub
```

You can also do this on a **Select Case Statement**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged

        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()

        Select Case ComboBox1.Text
            Case "Vehicles"
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("Sportscar")
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("Sedan")
            Case "Motorbikes"
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("Harley Davidson")
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("Some motorbikes")
            Case Else

        End Select


    End Sub
```

Comment: `TextChanged` is not the appropriate event for a `ComboBox` unless you actually want to react to the user typing into it like a `TextBox`, which would be rare. `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` are the events you want. Also, that's a rather dodgy solution as it requires more and more code as you get more items in either list. If you do it the right way, it's the same code no matter the items.