# COMBOBOX FUNCIONALITY

Tags: vb.net

[image: Screenshot of the form]
The code below is derived from vb form. As you can see there are 1,2,3,4 combobox with relationship hierachy ie combobox4 bares some characteristics form combobox3 and so forth. Now the issue is, when I choose lets say MOMBASA in combobox 3 and later change it to KERICHO, combobox4 updates values related to both MOMBASA and KERICHO instead of KERICHO alone.

I want to be able to make different selections in combobox3  and make combobox4 updated with relative values only or if i select another value in combobox2, combobox3 and 4 goes blank till I do a fresh selection from combox 3 all the way down

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (ComboBox3.Text = "MOMBASA") And ComboBox2.Text = "MP" Or (ComboBox3.Text = "MOMBASA") And ComboBox2.Text = "MCA" Then

        Label4.Visible = True
        ComboBox4.Visible = True
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("CHANGAMWE")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("JOMVU")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("KISAUNI")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("LIKONI")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("MVITA")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("NYALI")

    End If
    If (ComboBox3.Text = "KERICHO") And ComboBox2.Text = "MP" Or (ComboBox3.Text = "KERICHO") And ComboBox2.Text = "MCA" Then

        Label4.Visible = True
        ComboBox4.Visible = True
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("BELGUT")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("BURETI")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("KERICHO EAST")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("KIPKELION")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("LONDIANI")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("SOIN SIGOWET")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You keep asking the same question over and over, accepting the answer but, apparently, ignoring it. You were already told you `Clear` the `Items` in a previous answer and here you are, asking the same thing again.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i don't think I asked the same question before. The previous ones  were about the boxes appearing and disappearing on certain selections. Everything that I am being told here I am taking into consideration and it is really helping me. I am making big steps.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651213/parent-child-comboboxes) includes a call to clear the items. You haven't included that in your code here, then asked why your list doesn't "go blank".

Comment: You also keep asking how to do things that you wouldn't have to do at all if you had listened to my advice on how to do this properly in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to remove all the items before adding the items.

```
ComboBox4.Items.Clear()
```

And also have that in your ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: thanks a lot for your patience and time. You helped me out.